# how to apply conditional attribute to a div

Tags: angularjs

I have a div like this:

```
<div ng-switch-when="checkbox">
```

I would like to add a conditional `style` attribute to it when the length of an array in my scope is `> 5`

I tried this but it isn't working

```
<div ng-switch-when="checkbox" ng-attr-class="{{myArray.length > 5 && 'style='height:250px; overflow:scroll;''}}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a class in your CSS file, say `.overflow`.
Then do this:

```
<div ng-class="{'overflow' : myArray.length > 5}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create some class first with these style:

```
.extraStyle{
  height:250px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

then apply **ng-class** in div:

```
<div ng-switch-when="checkbox" 
     ng-class="{extraStyle:myArray.length > 5}">
```

**Notice**: You should use data- with all directives if you want your code to be proper for HTML5 standars. For Example:

> data-ng-class

Answer (score 0):

you can define your style in your css file, for example:

```
.mystyle{
   height:250px; 
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

then you can add this class to your div as an ng-class

```
<div ng-class="{mystyle: mycondition}"></div>
```